# Httpwebrequest fails with Not Found error : windows phone 8

Tags: .net, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

i am trying to post a httpwebrequest to a Rest  service from   windows phone 8 , with the  http headers :User-agent =@"Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows Phone 8.0;Trident/6.0; IEMobile/10.0; ARM; Touch; Microsoft; Virtual)"
And the post post body :payload=testvalue&item1=value;

the same request does returns a response when  posted  from a REST client

and below is the exception occured in windows phone 8 code

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
HResult=-2146233079
Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
Source=System.Windows
InnerException: System.Net.WebException
HResult=-2146233079
Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
Source=System.Windows
InnerException:
```

Comment: Make sure you're using a stream copy on post rather than stream -> unicode string -> stream

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the interesting part - NotFound is a very generic error, that can tell you that either the request failed internally or the web service rejected your request.

To get a better idea of what is going on, wrap it in a `try`/`catch` block (for a `WebException`) and read the response:

```
try
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(respResult);
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Report back with results and I will be able to help you more.

Comment: Hi Den below is the details  of the exception,hope you get some info on the issue ,                                                System.Net.WebException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
  Source=System.Windows
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote server returned an error: NotFound.
       Source=System.Windows
       InnerException:

Comment: That's not the problem - you're giving me exception details. Check my edited answer to see what I mean.

Comment: Hi Den  from the response details for the exception i was able to resolve the issue Thanks